# Adding a link to an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, banner

I am fairly new to JavaScript
I am wanting to add an ad banner to my site that changes the image of an ad on refresh.

So far I have this:

```
<div align="center"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
var img=new Array();
img[img.length]="image1.jpeg";
img[img.length]="image2.jpeg";
img[img.length]="image3.jpeg";
img[img.length]="image4.jpeg";
img[img.length]="image5.jpeg";
var rand=Math.round(Math.random()*(img.length-1));
document.write("<img src='" + img[rand] + "' border='0' />");
//--></script></div>
```

Can anyone please advise me on how to make the images link out?
Thank you. 
Kev

Comment: I'm guessing you know that you're assigning all the images to the same index, which is 0....

Comment: As I said. I'm new. I don't know that at all.

Comment: That's what forums like this are for. To help me learn.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said. Take a look at the answer and if you need anything clarified I can explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a  tag and wrap it.

```
 <div align="center"><script type="text/javascript">
    var img=new Array();
    img[img.length]="image1.jpeg";
    img[img.length]="image2.jpeg";
    img[img.length]="image3.jpeg";
    img[img.length]="image4.jpeg";
    img[img.length]="image5.jpeg";
    var rand=Math.round(Math.random()*(img.length-1));
    document.write("<a href="#"><img src='" + img[rand] + "' border='0' /><\/a>");
</script></div>
```

Your `img[img.length]` aren't doing much as they all assign the photos to img[0] because the array is emtpy. I would loop through and push like so:

```
var numberOfImages = 5;

for(var i=0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
    img[i].push('image'+(i+1)+'.jpeg'); //or =
}
```

Another note, the photos must be in the same directory/level as the js file as you are referencing the photos with no other path.

Final code:

```
 <div align="center"><script type="text/javascript">
    var img=new Array(),
        numberOfImages = 5; //However many images there are

    for(var i=0; i < numberOfImages; i++) { //Looping through numbers 0-4 inclusive to have 5 images
        img[i].push('image'+i+'.jpeg'); //or img[i] = 'image'+(i+1)+'.jpeg' This line adds/appends to the array.
        //That means when you do img[2] for example, it will return the 3rd image, which is 'image3.jpeg'. If you want to do img[3] to return image3, just add 1 to numberOfImages and var i = 1.

    }

    var rand=Math.round(Math.random()*(img.length-1));
    document.write("<a href="#"><img src='" + img[rand] + "' border='0' /><\/a>");
</script></div>
```

## If your images are from different sources or not local and the links are not modular,

You could just add the links to the array, then use the array index.

```
img[0] = "first image link";
img[1] = "second image link"; //and so on
```

Then,

```
document.write("<a href='" + img[rand] + "'><img src='" + img[rand] + "' border='0' /><\/a>");
```

Comment: So where does the numberOfImages go? In the same script?

Comment: Of course. It goes in place of the img[img.length] stuff because this is looping through 0-4 and appending image strings. So, you get a random number 0-4, getting the image. I will include the code in the answer

Comment: Does that allow for each image to have its own unique link?

Comment: If the links are modular then that would be easy, such as www.somewebsite.com/images/image1.jpeg, image2.jpeg, etc. If they are all from different sources you could either upload it to your site and give direct links such as www.yourwebsite.com/images/image1.jpeg or I would have to edit my answer :). Also, you modify the links in href, which is set to "#" at the moment.

Comment: All ad banners will be uploaded to my sites server and linked to the URL of my site including the http:// ext

Comment: In that case go with the stuff below the bold. Manual assign the links by doing `img[index]` then using that as the link